# Spring Autowiring fails

Tags: spring

I have added one Listener in web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>*.LoadCacheServlet</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

This is servlet class

```
@Component
public class LoadCacheServlet implements ServletContextListener {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectorRepository connectorRepository;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        LOGGER.info("ServletContextListener destroyed----------------------------");
    }

    // Run this before web application is started
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        LOGGER.info("ServletContextListener startedddd---------------------------------");
        connectorRepository.callMe("xys");
    }
}
```

On tomcat startup. contextInitialized method gets exceuted but connectorRepository is not initailized. ConnectorRepository  is an interface and in other parts of application its gets autowired by SpringJPA module. How to initialize it in servlet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656046/autowired-in-servletcontextlistener

Comment: Thanks. yes its duplicate